# Using gradle wrapper behind proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use a global `gradle.properties` file in my `.gradle` folder that looks like following:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<PW>
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<PROXY>
systemProp.http.proxyUser=<USERNAME>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<PW>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<PROXY>
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<USERNAME>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080

// line breaks added for readablilty only!!!
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-Dhttp.proxyHost\=<PROXY> -Dhttp.proxyPort\=8080 
-Dhttp.proxyUser\=<USERNAME> -Dhttp.proxyPassword\=<PW>
-Dhttps.proxyHost\=<PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyPort\=8080
-Dhttps.proxyUser\=<USERNAME> -Dhttps.proxyPassword\=<PW>

org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

#Settings for this computer
JAVA_HEAP_SIZE=3g
```

If I try to use the gradle wrapper I get following error:

```
Error:Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

**Downloading android studio updates, foreign projects from maven, jitpack and similar all works fine => those can use the provided proxy settings correctly!**

But the gradle wrapper can't download anything. Similar issues on SO seem to solve the problem by adding the proxy the way I already do it and it seems to work for them.

What am I missing? Where do I have to setup the proxy for the gradle wrapper?